# Wrapping Multiple Columns in a Single COlumn

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

7 tables. In each table there is a common entity called fisherid. I have four fields in each table that is CreatedBy, createdDate, LastModifiedBy and LastModifiedDate. These fields are keeping track of last operation date and user name on that table. Now the problem is that i need to show history of fisher, that is what a user done on a particular fisher. I have 3 columns in my grid that is ActivityDate, UserName and Description. What i need is to display something like this

```
ActivityDate     User          Description

------------ ----------- ---------------------------

11/12/2010    Test User         Updated Address
12/12/2010    Alexander         Created Note
```

Let me explain you the above. If in a table say address if a user Test User updates any field then the query must be able to say your address field has been updated or can pull the action based on lastmodified date and lastmodifiedbyuser field(if they are not null or blank).  Similar for all tables. If CreatedBy and CreatedDate are null then no history will be displayed. If only createdDate and createby are filled then created table name or proper message will be displayed.

I hope the scenario is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly I think you need something like this?

```
SELECT 
    isnull(LastModifiedDate,createdDate) as ActivityDate,
    isnull(LastModifiedBy,createdBy) as User ....
```

Comment: So you want to say if i have multiple columns then i should need something like this IsNull(Table1.LastModifiedDate,Table2.LastModifiedDate, Table3.CreatedDate) as ActivityDate or i can only operate it on one table. Please make me more clear.

Comment: You can operate on more than table, so long as the tables are joined properly, e.g. `SELECT ISNULL(Table1.LastModifiedDate, Table2.LastModifiedDate, Table3.CreatedDate) as ActivityDate FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 WHERE Table1.fisherid = Table2.fisherid AND Table1.fisherid = Table3.fisherid`

Comment: if i am running this query in Sql Server 2008 i am getting the following error message [Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The isnull function requires 2 argument(s)].

Comment: Anyways guys thanks for your help. I solved it following another approach, that in every insert and update SP, i am insert the above 3 details  in a new table called tlHistory and from there i can easily fetch the result. thanks anyway... thanks for sharing time... :)

Comment: @Malvolio No, you can't. ISNULL() only takes two parameters. You need to use COALESCE() for that, wich returns the first value that is not NULL for all the inputs.

Comment: Really?  That's silly then: ISNULL is just one particular case of COALESCE.  SQL is an endless font of face-palming moments.  Thanks for the correction.